# Is that possible to preload existing program?

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium, multitouch-keyboard

I'm working at touch Awesomium-based web brower. I have to use Windows 8 touch keyboard as main browser keyboard. I'm starting process named `tabtip.exe`:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\tabtip.exe");
```

Is possible to preload that app to make it starting faster?

Comment: What do you mean by preload? Is that a .net program? Are you talking about pre-jit?

Comment: @up It's just touch-keyboard for user input. The keyboard loads slowly and I want to load it faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in a WPF Application that would enable you to call any code before the Framework has been loaded. Normally, your earliest possible opportunity to call the `Process.Start` method would be in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` constructor.

However, you could possibly cheat a little, depending on how important this requirement is for you. It *is* possible to open another `Window` other than the `MainWindow` (such as a splash screen) and then when you're ready and the external program has been started, open `MainWindow`.

If you're interested in this suggestion, please take a look at my answer to the [How to open a child Window like a splash screen before MainWindow in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299924/how-to-open-a-child-window-like-a-splash-screen-before-mainwindow-in-wpf/24302981#24302981) question, which will guide you through that process.

Comment: I know about splash screens and other windows. I have externall (touch keyboard) app which starts when button is touched. The keyboard sometimes starts very slowly, so I want to start it faster